# Сравнение лиц по фотографии

Tags: c#, изображения, искусственный-интеллект, распознавание

есть идея реализации системы распознания лиц, после чего нужно будет сравнивать с уже имеющимися фотографиями. Т.е. есть веб-камера она во время запуска приложения будет находить лицо, делать фотографию и сравнивать с базой уже имеющихся лиц (2-3х штук). Ну и, соответственно, говорить кто это. 
Нашел в интернете фреймворк, который умеет находить на кадре изображения лица. Называется Accord.
Вот таким образом я нахожу лица на фотографии:

```
        const string pathInputImage = "input.jpg";
        const string pathOutputImage = "output.jpg";

        // загружаем изображение
        System.Drawing.Bitmap image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(pathInputImage);

        HaarObjectDetector faceDetector = new HaarObjectDetector(
                  // указываем, что нужно искать лица
                  new FaceHaarCascade(),
                  // устанавливаем возможный минимальный размер
                  minSize: 25,
                  // устанавливаем режим поиска, при котором если область
                  // обнаружена, то поиск во внутренних и пересекающихся
                  // областях производиться не будет. Это позволяет сэкономить время
                  // работы, но если лица находятся очень близко друг от друга, то
                  // возможно потребуется другой режим
                  searchMode: ObjectDetectorSearchMode.NoOverlap);

        // создаём объект, который нужен для выделения объектов на изображении
        RectanglesMarker facesMarker = new RectanglesMarker(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
        // распознаём лица
        facesMarker.Rectangles = faceDetector.ProcessFrame(image);
        // выделяем лица на изображении
        facesMarker.ApplyInPlace(image);

        // сохраняем изображение
        image.Save(pathOutputImage);
```

Соответственно вопрос правильно ли я реализую поиск лиц для моего проекта и как можно теперь сравнить их с четкой фотографией лица. Может кто-то знает фреймворки основанные на нейронке, что умеет такое делать. 
Сам не умею писать нейронки, поэтому не могу реализовать самостоятельно. В интернете нашел только сравнение картинок с текстом, путем распознание текста и сравнивание его. Но у меня явно должна использоваться другая технология.

Comment: во-первых это не исскуственный интелект, а нейронные сети. А во-вторых я бы начинал изучение языка с чего-то намноооого проще.

Comment: SIFT, SURF, Виола-Джонсон - в добрый путь :). Нравиться мне нынешняя молодежь - главное найти "фреймворк".